# How to cast char[n][length+1] to constant array of strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array of 10 strings of length at most 20 that I'm building up

```
char buffer[10][20] = {0};
//populate the buffer with 10 strings
//after this point, no more changes to the buffer allowed
//make a new pointer to indicate that I want the buffer finalized
const char **finalized = buffer;
```

But the previous fails with the warning

```
 warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

Doing something similar with a single string works

```
char buffer[20] = {0};
//populate the buffer
const char *finalized = buffer;
```

What is the proper way to cast in the first case?

Comment: `{0}` is an initializer of a *one*-dimensional array.

Comment: @Eugene Sh.: No. Moreover, it is absurd. In C language `{ 0 }` is an idiomatic universal zero-initializer. It can be used to zero-initialize absolutely *anything*.

Comment: Yes, but not without complaining, e.g. `warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]`. (enabled as part of `-Wall`)

Comment: @David C. Rankin: Well, don't enable it then. I remember that a few years ago GCC enabled it by default and got their heads bashed in for ruining something as useful and quintessential as `{ 0 }` with a stupid warning. Now it is no longer enabled by default. But the fact that they don't give `{ 0 }` special treatment in `-Wall` mode indicates that someone still doesn't know what they are doing there.

Comment: I'm not knocking the warning. I had always just matched braces -- glad to know that was precatory. Added *idiomatic universal zero-initializer* to C toolbox `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to "cast" a regular 2D array to a pointer-to-pointer type. These types are completely incompatible and have completely different semantics. You can force the cast, but the result will be useless anyway.

Formally, the proper pointer type in this case is `char (*)[20]`

```
char (*finalized)[20] = buffer;
```

except that const-correctness rules of C language won't allow you to add a `const` there. You can force it though

```
const char (*finalized)[20] = (const char (*)[20]) buffer;
```

You can also do

```
char (*finalized)[10][20] = &buffer;
```

Whether this is of any use to you - I don't know since you do not provide any details about what's that for.

Comment: I want to pass the finalized array to execv. In `man 3 exec` I see that execv requires a `char *const argv[]`, Does this help? There must be some way to cast, otherwise how could you use exec with variable arguments?

Comment: @nullUser: A cast will not help you here. You will have to build that `argv` separately. `argv` is an *array of pointers*. Your `buffer` is an *array of arrays*, which is a completely different thing. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2275818/187690 for further details.

Comment: @nullUser you should mention your requirements in the question

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 2D array, you cannot simply convert it to a pointer to pointer. pointers and arrays are not the same.

If you want strings of at more length 19, then you need to make the number of strings flexible in this case, using `char (*)[20]`, as pointed out by @AnT.

**Note:** using `20` as a dimension means that you can have at most `19` characters, because one space must occupy the null terminating character `\0`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRLEN 20
#define NUMSTR 10

int main(void) {
    char buffer[NUMSTR][STRLEN];

    strcpy(buffer[0], "Hello");
    strcpy(buffer[1], "World");

    char (*finalized)[STRLEN] = buffer;

    printf("%s %s!\n", finalized[0], finalized[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the case of assigning *string literals* you could simply do `char *buffer[] = { "Hello", "World" ); printf ("%s %s\n", buffer[0], buffer[1]);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Its a bit hard to integrate that with `buffer[10][20];`. I'm fairly certain using that would end up with conflicting types. Perhaps `strncpy` would be a better alternative.